# Range of angle made by focal chord of a parabola at the vertex.

Tags: conic-sections

How to determine the range of angle which a focal chord of a parabola (considering a standard parabola $ y^2 =4ax $) subtend at the vertex.

My attempt:Take $ t_1$ and $ t_2$ two points on the para bola.  We have the relation $ t_1 t_2 =-1$. How to move further?

Comment: Rather you mean the *points* $(at^2,2at)$ for parameters $t_1$ and $t_2$.

Comment: Exactly I mean by that points only.